# Will Grub2 be replaced with Windows bootloader if i do a fresh windows 8 install? (upgrade assistant)

Tags: windows, windows-8, bootloader, grub2, windows-8-upgrade

Help! If i upgrade from Windows 7 to 8 using the upgrade assistant and choose to overwrite Windows 7 and delete all files, will the current MSR (Grub2) be replaced with the Windows MSR?  i sure hope so couse Grub has been a pain in the ass since i upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and everything stoped working. I fixed the problem with Grub using "Boot-repair" after sitting next to my other computer throug the hole day trying to find a solution, and now i just want it as far away as possible!

Comment: Yes...It will be replaced but you can easily replace the new windows bootloader with Grub2. You will have to do that otherwise you won't be able to boot into Ubuntu.  I suggest asking any questions about Ubuntu on the community forums there are lots of helpful people within the Ubuntu community.

Comment: No, EFI bootloaders in windows are friendly. Usually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Grub2Win which is available here http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win

It uses the native Windows bootloader and is configured from windows. It will allow you to dual-boot Linux easily.